# Unresolved external symbol when assigning a function pointer to a function imported by DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, function-pointers

I wasn't able to find a post with this particular issue. This is all in C, on a Windows target.

I have a DLL that I created, and some client code I created to test the DLL. The functions and types defined in the DLL are all successfully resolved by the client code **except** when I try to use a function pointer in the client code to a function defined in DLL.

Example:

```c
/*--- DLL_Header.h ---*/
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_API void library_function(int foo, int bar);
```

```c
/* --- DLL_source.c --- */
void library_function(int foo, int bar)
{
  /* Do anything */
}
```

```c
/* --- Client Code --- */
#include "DLL_Header.h"

void client_function_A()
{
   int foo = 1;
   int bar = 2;
   library_function(foo,bar); /* This compiles and links with no problem! */
}

void client_function_B()
{
   void (*lib_exec)(int foo, int bar);
   
   lib_exec = &library_function;    /* Compiles but then linker says unresolved external symbol __imp__library_function */

   int x = 1;
   int y = 2;
   lib_exec(x,y);
}
```

`client_function_B` works fine if I just statically link everything, so it seems there is something I am not fundamentally understanding about the interaction between the DLL and function pointers. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and why?

**Edit:** Exact error message

`client_code.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__library_function referenced in function _client_function_B`

Comment: did you have BUILD_DLL set correctly when building the exe?

Comment: I think so, because `client_function_A`  had no problems from the linker when resolving `library_function`.  Wouldn't both client functions raise an unresolved error if I messed up setting the BUILD_DLL?

Comment: "This compiles and links with no problem" and "Unresolved external symbol" contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if I just comment out `client_function_B` and try to build the exe with just `client_function_A`, I don't run into issues (compiles/links with no problem). If I try to also include `client_function_B`, the linker raises and error and explicitly tells me the problem is in `client_function_B`.

Comment: this code doesnt compile and link so all bets are off, also feels like you are editing various bits and pieces on the fly. Best thing is to use the imports and exports commands on the dll and exe